# Movie where alien on spaceship replicates people and then electrocutes them

Tags: story-identification, movie, sy-fy

Things I remember from the movie. 
A plump man in an electronic wheelchair being electrocuted. 
One spaceship running in to another and it kills a woman being stabbed in the stomach. 
The main killer alien is blonde. I don’t think he talks unless he’s taken over someone’s body. 
The title of the movie has shadow or star in it maybe?

Answer (score 5):

[***Project Shadowchaser III***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114192/) (AKA Project Shadowchaser 3000, AKA Shadowchaser III, AKA Edge Of Darkness).

Came across this while I've been up all night trying to figure out the movie myself. Saw it as a kid and remembered the blonde hair and replication. I remembered the guy in the wheelchair.

Also I'd like to add that it's an advanced android, but definitely could be remembered as an alien.

Comment: Any film with *four separate titles* must be good!